# Conditional probability routine question

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability

> Of the employees that work for Hapolonians Incorporated, 35 percent
>   have an MBA and 40 percent are over the age of 35.  Of those employees
>   that have an MBA, 30 percent are over the age of 35.
>
> Calculate the probability that a randomly chosen employee has both an
>   MBA and is over the age of 35.

How would I approach this? Not looking for the answer.

So far I've reviewed the rules of probability and under the intersection rule 
- $P(A ∩ B) = P(A|B)\cdot P(B)$ - the symbol between the A AND B on the right side of the equal sign stands for "given", is this a good approach?

Comment: Please consider adding the [tag:self-study] tag and read its wiki.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Yup, it looks like you are exactly on the right track.  So you know P(B) and P(A|B), correct?